# Empty response from server when connecting with python socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

I am trying to connect to URL `https://www.ssehl.co.uk/HALO/publicLogon.do` in Python.

The simple solution using `requests` fails:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.ssehl.co.uk/HALO/publicLogon.do')
print r.text
```

with error

```
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 327, in send
raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.ssehl.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /HALO/publicLogon.do (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: '')
```

so I tried to get the raw response from the server using library `socket`:

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print 'Failed to create socket'
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Created'
host = 'www.ssehl.co.uk';
port = 443;

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

#Connect to remote server
s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip

#Send some data to remote server
message = "GET /HALO/publicLogon.do HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

try :
   #Set the whole string
   s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
   #Send failed
   print 'Send failed'
   sys.exit()

print 'Message send successfully'

#Now receive data
reply = s.recv(4096)

print reply
```

will output:

```
Socket Created
Socket Connected to www.ssehl.co.uk on ip 161.12.7.194
Message send successfully
Reply:
```

after reply there is some garbage which I can't paste, however this is a sublime console screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxC62.png)

Is there any way to get a 200 response from the server, just like a browser?

Comment: Hmm, the code using `requests` works for me. The `requests.get` line returns `<Response [200]>`, while the `r.text` part returns the webpage correctly. Probably temporary error on the server yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when you use either Python's built in stuff (urllib2, requests, httplib) or even command line stuff (curl, wget) over https the server spazzes out and gives an erroneous response.

However when you request the page over regular http, it works fine, for example:

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ssehl.co.uk/HALO/publicLogon.do').getcode()
```

prints out

```
>> 200
```

My guess is that their servers are configured wrong and your browser somehow deals with it silently.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I used port `80`. Sooo:
`port = 80;`
There must be some error when using **HTTPS** servers thought Python...

 
Also, you are sending wrong request. You are not sending the `hostname`. 
Fixed request:
`message = "GET /HALO/publicLogon.do HTTP/1.1\r\nHostname: %s\r\n\r\n"%host`

---

So **[here](http://randomgalaxy.com/stackoverflow/empty-response-from-server-when-connecting-with-python-socket/sock.py)** is working code.

---

### I think the problem exists, because port `443` is *encrypted*. And Python doesn't support encryption (probably).

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ssl.wrap_socket** if you want support https.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html for details.